# What does icon size means?

Tags: uninstall, icons, boot-repair

Looking for boot repair program, I looked at this:

[image]

What does the size icon means? If they the same, why two icons? And the most important, how to uninstall the needless one?

Comment: I think you've got two `.desktop` files in `/usr/share/applications/` for your program. You could check to see if that's true, and remove the duplicate one